# SQL Server 2012 - The application has failed to start because its side-biy-side configuration is incorrect

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

When opening Sql Server Management Studio I'm getting the following error message:

[image]

Then when I have a look at the Event Viewer the following message is displayed related to this:

Activation context generation failed for "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ssms.exe". Dependent Assembly debuggerproxy.dll,processorArchitecture="X86",type="win32",version="1.0.0.0" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

Also the Installer won't work.

Any solution for this please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Open an elevated command prompt (Run As Admin)
- Type `sfc /scannow`

The sfc /scannow command will scan all protected system files, and replace corrupted files with a cached copy that is located in a compressed folder at %WinDir%\System32\dllcache. The %WinDir% placeholder represents the Windows operating system folder.